# Type casting a structure member

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have structure(A) and it takes another structure(B) as member.
Now i want structure C as member of A instead of B.
Both B and C are of same type

```
typedef struct
{
 int a;
 B b;
}A

typedef struct
{
 int a;
}B

typedef struct
{
 int a;
}C
```

How can i assign struct C as member instead of B. How to do typecasting 
Please help

Comment: Are you looking for a way to swap the struct member data on runtime?

Comment: No i want to pass my own structure to struct A or need C as member by typecasting

Comment: When you say B and C are the same type, do you mean they inherit from something or they contain the same kind of data?

Comment: Both B and C are of same type right... THen y cant i make C as member

Comment: @slycrel  Same kind of data onl

Comment: Which of the three languages you've tagged are you really working in?  If the visual-c++ tag is correct then obviously you're NOT using objective-c.  I'll go ahead and remove that one but you really need to decide what you're using so people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing why you want to do this, its hard to recommend a strategy. Here are a few options though.

Option 1: Use Templates. (C++ only)

```
template <type T>
struct A
{
  int a;
  T* t;
};

struct Foo
{
  int a;
};

struct B : public Foo
{
};

struct C : public Foo
{
};

struct A<Foo> A_foo;

struct B;
struct C;

A_foo.t = &B; //OK! This can now take pointer to any class that extends Foo.
A_foo.t = &C; //OK!
```

Option 2: Make struct A contain a void* (not recommended, you will lose all type safety). (Both C/C++)

```
struct A 
{
  int a;
  void* foo; // you can now assign any pointer to foo :-S
};
```

Comment: The post was tagged C++. Thanks for the comment I have clarified my post!

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ are statically typed languages. You can't do it. If you declare something as apple, it will stay as apple until the end of the times.

Answer (score 1):

Although they appear to be the same type (and are, in this simple case, identical) they are considered to be different types by the compiler. This makes sense for more complex cases or in C++ where the type system is more complex than in pure C.

You generally shouldn't rely on compiler tricks or hackery to do this sort of assignment. Instead, do it properly. Either directly assign fields or, to simplify code, create a helper function along these lines:

```
void ASetBWithC(A *a, C c) {
    assert(a != NULL);
    a->b.a = c.a;
}
```

C++ also has the assignment operator which you could overload to do your work for you (instead of creating a named helper function) but I suspect this is beyond your current comfort level.